# official nginx trusty ppa gives KEYEXPIRED gpg error

Tags: apt, repository, nginx

I'm getting the following error every time I do apt-get upgrade:

GPG error: http://nginx.org trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1471427554

I just have the official nginx ppa installed the standard way, by having added the following to my sources.list

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
```

Is this an error from their end that they will eventually fix hopefully, or is there something I'm going to have to do from my end?

Comment: Did you download [this key from NGINX](http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key), then run `sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key` and still getting this error?

Comment: this happens ... sometimes. But this ("1471427554") does not look like a valid GPG key.
`wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key -O - |sudo  apt-key add -` will do both steps suggested by @ThomasWard in one small command.

Comment: `LANG=C sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1471427554`
returns the following error:

`Executing: /tmp/tmp.EU8uLKmT5b/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
    keys.gnupg.net
    --recv-keys
    1471427554
    gpg: "1471427554" not a key ID: skipping`

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann I see what you're saying, but maybe they copy-pasted or such.  (We need them to reply to whether they added the key or not...)

Comment: @Mohamed-Hafez Please, post in the question the output of `wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key -O - |sudo apt-key add - ` commands (@Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann comment)

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann's comment worked!! one suggestion, could I have used https in the address to be more secure? too late for me but just checking for anyone else who might see this

Comment: yes, the key file is available via https as well.

Comment: @Phillip: Actually, 1471427554 is the timestamp of the expiry time for the APT signing key. Modern versions of the date command will parse it to readable format for you: `date -u -d @1471427554` gives `Wed Aug 17 09:52:34 UTC 2016`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After adding a third party repository to a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` file or `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you need to make sure the corresponding gpg key is inserted into the apt keystore.

To be more specific for this special case of nginx.org repository: you need to add the nginx.org gpg key file used for the signing of the repository.

This can be done by either downloading the file https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key manually and issue `sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key` (as suggested by [nginx.org](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable) and @ThomasWard) or you can do this in one single line:

```
wget https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Ok, this worked, but I must be misreading, or missing something. Why did this suddenly pop up now? I don't get that.

Comment: @linsong described why this popped up now: the old gpg key had expired on August, 17. So you needed to download the new key.

Answer (score 11):

The root cause of this problem is because the "older" Nginx signing key expired on Aug 17, 2016:

```
$ sudo apt-key list

pub   2048R/7BD9BF62 2011-08-19 [expired: 2016-08-17]
uid                  nginx signing key <signing-key@nginx.com>
```

To fix this issue, add the new signing key using the command as suggested by @phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann and @ThomasWard:

```
wget https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

The new key now expires in 2024:

```
$ sudo apt-key list

pub   2048R/7BD9BF62 2011-08-19 [expires: 2024-06-14]
uid                  nginx signing key <signing-key@nginx.com>
```

Comment: I think that I like this answer overall overall since it attempts to explain what happened better. (The above explanation didn't fit with my use case despite the response.)